# How to get number of related video with YouTube API?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-data-api

I want to get the number of related video and all video list using API V3.
For example,
If I input the URL of the video, I want get how many related videos of my video at that time and get all related video list(title and URL etc..) 
Is that possible to do in Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple javascript function to get data from youtube api v3.

```
function Get(yourUrl)
{
var Httpreq = new XMLHttpRequest(); // a new request
Httpreq.open("GET",yourUrl,false);
Httpreq.send(null);
return Httpreq.responseText;         
}
```

Call the function and use the data in json

```
var json_obj = JSON.parse(Get("yourUrl"));
console.log("this is the author name: "+json_obj.ObjectvalueWhateveritis);
```

Here your url is

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={$this->key}&part={$part}&maxResults={$this->limit}&type=video&relatedToVideoId={$id}
```

Hope it helps you.